# How to prevent “Scheduling restart of crashed service”?

Tags: android

I find the logcat says "Scheduling restart of crashed service com.qcma.kuo/.keepalive.account.SyncServiceNew in 1000ms".

but app(com.qcma.kuo) is already uninstall.I just want to know what cause that happens? I think there is no error for my code.So does anybody know what cause it and is there any way to prevent this happen?

```
public class SyncServiceNew extends Service {

private static final Object sSyncAdapterLock = new Object();
private static SyncAdapter sSyncAdapter = null;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    startDaemonCoreService();
    synchronized (sSyncAdapterLock) {
        if (sSyncAdapter == null) {
            sSyncAdapter = new SyncAdapter(getApplicationContext(), true);
        }
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    if (sSyncAdapter == null)
        return null;

    return sSyncAdapter.getSyncAdapterBinder();
}

private void startDaemonCoreService() {
    CoreService.startCoreService(this, null, CoreServiceStartType.TYPE_ACCOUNT_SYNC_START);
}
}

    <service
        android:name="com.qcma.kuo.keepalive.account.SyncServiceNew"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process="com.qcma.kuo">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
            android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
    </service>
```